# Convert MP3 to OGG for HTML5 <audio> playback on shared hosting

Tags: html5-audio

HTML5 comes witj audio tag, but Firefox preffers OGG while IE preffers MP3. My php app has a form which allows users to upload audio files. The question is how do I transform an mp3 file format to ogg in order to play them on most browser.

i've read somewhere that ffmpeg can do this task. Can I do it on goddady if I have a linux deluxe hosting account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you **cannot** do this on any cheap hosting environment which does not allow you to install your own binaries.

Get a cheap Linux VPS to make sure you have 100% control over the software stack to install ffmpeg and use it for converting and double encoding files in both MP3 and OGG. Alternatively, try AAC and OGG, as AAC is has better mobile support and browsers supporting MP3 support AAC in any case.

Linux VPS providers can be found e.g. from http://lowendbox.com/

You can also use premium service like http://encoding.com/ to host audio for you.